# Views paragraph fields in block Twig template

Tags: views, blocks, paragraphs

I understand that I can use content['#view'].field['field_name'].value(rowcount) to get a value of a field.

But how can I refer to fields of a paragraph field, that is in a view block in a file like "block--views-block--NAME.html.twig"?

Comment: `field_name'  can contain a paragraph field, depending on how you've configured the field in Views.

Comment: if I put in the name of the paragraph field there is no output.

Comment: I added the paragraph field in the view with configuration 'Entity' and 'viewmode' Standard.

Comment: and the paragraph field has of course several entries, so I will need another loop. But how to adress it?